# How to update table row multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help I  can not update all the values stored in column views, I want to add random numbers.

I have over 300 videos and I want to update all the views records.

A small example here what does not work, only if I update a single row this is working.

```
UPDATE videos SET views VALUES ( 1234, 2234, 3455, 4564 ) WHERE user_id = 3;
```

What exactly is wrong here i try to find solutions  on Google but unfortunately nothing found to help me.

Thank you so much!!

[Example Table]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvsww.png)

Comment: You wants to put all '1234, 2234, 3455, 4564' together in column Views?

Comment: Syntax for update query is UPDATE table_name SET field_name = value WHERE your_condition You should read a little on how to write Update query. It's simple one, not that difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add random numbers

You could use:

```
UPDATE videos 
SET views  = FLOOR(1 + RAND() *1000)
WHERE user_id = 3;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62ec2b4973bcfd132a1a85d710089187)**

Comment: FLOOR(1000 + RAND() *10000) is what I made from it, it works perfect. I really need to study more to understand everything I am excited to learn even more.